# How can I concatenate the 4 corners of the image quickly when loading image in deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, dataset, python-imaging-library

What is the most effective way to concatenate 4 corner, shown in [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mnKA.jpg) ?
(conducting in **getitem**())

```
left_img = Image.open('image.jpg')
...
output = right_img
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it.
Firstly I would convert the image to a Tensor Image temporarily

```
from torchvision import transforms
tensor_image = transforms.ToTensor()(image)
```

Now assuming you have a 3 channel image (although similiar principles apply to any matrices of any number of channels including 1 channel gray scale images).

You can find the Red channel with `tensor_image[0]` the Green channel with `tensor_image[1]` and the the Blue channel with `tensor_image[2]`

You can make a for loop iterating through each channel like

```
for i in tensor_image.size(0):
  curr_channel = tensor_image[i]
```

Now inside that for loop with each channel you can extract the

- First corner pixel with float(curr_channel[0][0])
- Last top corner pixel with float(curr_channel[0][-1])
- Bottom first pixel with float(curr_channel[-1][0])
- Bottom and last pixel with float(curr_channel[-1][-1])

Make sure to convert all the pixel values to float or double values before this next appending step

Now you have four values that correspond to the corner pixels of each channel
Then you can make a list called `new_image = []`
You can then append the above mentioned pixel values using
`new_image.append([[curr_channel[0][0], curr_channel[0][-1]], [curr_channel[-1][0], curr_channel[-1][-1]]])`
Now after iterating through every channel you should have a big list that contains three (or tensor_image.size(0)) number of lists of lists.

Next step is to convert this list of lists of lists to a torch.tensor by running

```
new_image = torch.tensor(new_image)
```

To make sure everything is right new_image.size() should return torch.Size([3, 2, 2])

If that is the case you now have your wanted image but it is tensor format.
The way to convert it back to PIL is to run

```
final_pil_image = transforms.ToPILImage()(new_image)
```

If everything went good, you should have a pil image that fulfills your task. The only code it uses is clever indexing and one for loop.
There is a possibility however if you look more than I can, then you can avoid using a for loop and perform operations on all the channels without the loop.

Sarthak Jain

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how quick this is but here:

```py
import numpy as np

img = np.array(Image.open('image.jpg'))

w, h = img.shape[0], image.shape[1]

# the window size:
r = 4

upper_left = img[:r, :r]
lower_left = img[h-r:, :r]

upper_right = img[:r, w-r:]
lower_right = img[h-r:, w-r:]

upper_half = np.concatenate((upper_left, upper_right), axis=1)
lower_half = np.concatenate((lower_left, lower_right), axis=1)
img = np.concatenate((upper_half, lower_half))
```

or short:

```py
upper_half = np.concatenate((img[:r, :r], img[:r, w-r:]), axis=1)
lower_half = np.concatenate((img[h-r:, :r], img[h-r:, w-r:]), axis=1)
img = np.concatenate((upper_half, lower_half))
```